# Broadcast audio to multiple receivers via Bluetooth

Tags: wireless, bluetooth

I want to be able to connect multiple Bluetooth devices to a Bluetooth transmitter, and then stream audio from a portable MP3 player, via Bluetooth, to all of the connected Bluetooth receivers. Is this even possible?

I thought of using the A2DP profile to stream audio. But is it possible to stream audio to multiple receivers?

I was hoping I could use a Bluetooth module for this, something like Bluegiga WT32. But perhaps I should use a micro controller, maybe an Arduino, instead?

Any help would be of great use!
/Johnny

Comment: Arduino is not able to handle such a high data rate I believe. You will need to use something on the level of Cortex M3/M4.

Comment: It might be worth looking into the Texas Instruments PurePath suite of parts: They offer some audio-over-RF SoCs and a range of parts with low latency high bit depth audio transmission over 2.4 GHz public band radio. I don't know of a specific product that does audio multicast for more than 4 channels, but IIRC they also have broadcast options in the PurePath family.

Answer (score 3):

Yes it is possible with high numbers of Bluetooth devices and a powerful processor at broadcast side i.e each and every Bluetooth acts as a dedicated channel serving a single device so more Bluetooth more channels , but it  is impractical if number of slaves go high

Answer (score 0):

I think you might need something like this that supports multiple slaves.
http://www.connectblue.com/products/classic-bluetooth-products/classic-bluetooth-modules/bluetooth-serial-port-module-obs433/

Comment: Does that one support A2DP?

Comment: I just found out that this module you recommended doesn't support A2DP, which is used when streaming audio.
But do you mean that I just have to find a module capable of multiple slaves?

Answer (score -2):

Bluetooth allows connection for 7 devices(slaves) simultaneously however only one connection can only be active at a time.

Comment: This is entirely incorrect. While the BT spec limits the connection count to different devices to 7 (not applicable for Bluetooth Smart), you can not only communicate with the 7 devices simultaneously, you can even have multiple l2cap links (logical channel) between each device. Of course, there are some practical limitations that vendor's implementation and the transmission path causes, meaning not all vendors support 7 connections simultaneously and when they do the throughputs may be very poor and the connections may drop.